# Add reference to netNamedPipeBinding in .Net 5

Tags: migrate, .net-5

i have class library project in .net framework 4.6.1. i have to migrate that project into .net 5.
while doing so I am facing error for netNamedPipeBinding.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NetNamedPipeBinding' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

following nuget package already installed.

```
System.ServiceModel.Duplex
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
System.ServiceModel.Primitives
```

Any way to to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not supported.

> **Named pipes**
> WCF provided a named pipes binding for communication between processes on the same physical machine. The first release of
> ASP.NET Core gRPC does not support named pipes. Adding client and
> server support for named pipes (and Unix domain sockets) is a goal for
> a future release.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/wcf-bindings#named-pipes

Also, the documentation page for `NamedPipeBinding` is resolved to `.NET 4.8` section and does not exist for `.NET 5`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding

`HttpBinding` documentation page is there for `.NET 5`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.nethttpbinding